# Serilog: Usage of additional properties

Tags: serilog

I'm trying to write additional properties to the log using {Properties} (which are not in the message template):

Used (FileSink) template:

```
"[{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Properties}{NewLine}{Exception}"
```

Log operation (simplified, normally the object array is given by a method parameter):

```
Log.Information("Start logging",
    new object[]{
        new { Version = "VersionString"},
        new { StartDate = DateTime.Now },
        new { Id = Guid.NewGuid() }
    });
```

I also tired:

```
Log.Information("Start logging",
    new object[]{
        "VersionString",
        DateTime.Now,
        Guid.NewGuid()
    });
```

I had a look on [LogEventPropertyCapturingTests](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/e42245c0db0931e1fffdd72a0729361c60e877bc/test/Serilog.Tests/Core/LogEventPropertyCapturingTests.cs) and [this PR](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/pull/779), but I couldn't get it working...

---

**Update**
I use wrapper functions like this:

```
public static void Information(string messageTemplate, object[] propertyValues, bool show = false, [CallerMemberName] string callerMethodeName = "", [CallerFilePath] string callerFilePath = "", [CallerLineNumber] int callerLineNumer = -1)
{
    using (LogContext.PushProperty("CallingContext", new { callerMethodeName, callerFilePath, callerLineNumer }))
    {
        _MainLog.Information(messageTemplate, propertyValues);
    }

    if(show)
    {
        // Code to show a the event to the user
    }
}
```

---

**Update2** Found a way but it's not very nice, as the template-property-matching rudimentary.

```
public static void Information(string messageTemplate, object[] propertyValues, bool show = false, [CallerMemberName] string callerMethodeName = "", [CallerFilePath] string callerFilePath = "", [CallerLineNumber] int callerLineNumer = -1)
{
    using (LogContext.PushProperty("CallingContext", new { callerMethodeName, callerFilePath, callerLineNumer }))
    {
        Regex matchProperties = new Regex("{[^}]+}");

        int usedPropertiesCount = matchProperties.Matches(messageTemplate).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).Distinct().Count();

        if (propertyValues.Length > usedPropertiesCount)
        {
            using (LogContext.PushProperty("AdditionalData", propertyValues.Skip(usedPropertiesCount)))
            {
                _MainLog.Information(messageTemplate, propertyValues);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _MainLog.Information(messageTemplate, propertyValues);
        }
    }

    if(show)
    {
        // Code to show a the event to the user
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ForContext()` method will do this:

```
Log.ForContext("Version", "VersionString")
    .ForContext("Id", Guid.NewGuid())
    .Information("Start logging");
```

(I've omitted `StartDate` because all Serilog events are already timestamped.)

[This blog post series](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/06/structured-logging-concepts-in-net-series-1/) includes some posts on message templates plus context and correlation that cover this plus other alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for your response! 
Unfortunately I don't know the count or the names of the properties in advance. I get them as object[] (I've updated my question)

Comment: Found a solution (see my question) but it isn't really nice:
- it assumes that the properties are in the same order as in the template
- all additional properties are not logged as 1st-level-level properties (have to put them unter some key)

For my case this is sufficient so I'm marking this as solved. But if you have an idea for a cleaner solution I'm open for it.